# How to convert GLTF to Adobe 3D PDF using automation

Tags: three.js, 3d, acrobat, scene, gltf

I'm Exporting a Three.js scene to GLTF format using GLTF exporter. And further I'm converting it to adobe 3D PDF with Tetra 4D conversion applications using some manual steps which works fine. Now I want to
make the manual steps automatic so that when I export it from the three.js scene, it should give me the output as 3D PDF.
I've tried using the trial SDK in my folder but not able to convert automatically. Any suggestions, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate the conversion of GLTF files to Adobe 3D PDFs, you can use Tetra4D Converter SDK. This SDK provides programming interfaces and sample code that can be integrated into your application to enable the conversion functionality.

Here are some useful resources:

- Tetra 4d documentation https://tetra4d.com/documentation/
- Acrobat SDK documentation, which contains detailed information on how to work with 3D PDF files. https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/sdk.html.
- Three.js documentation, to exporting scenes to GLTF format https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Export-via-Exporter.